# Changing default arguments of function, when function is generic

Tags: r, function

So a bit of a question for fun (I know it is bad practice, I'm not going to use it in production code or anything, so don't yell at me haha).

I want to write a function factory `fun0(fun)` that takes a function `fun` and defines a new function `{fun}0()` in the environment of our choice, that is exactly the same as `fun0` but with the default behaviour changed changed so that it is no longer `na.rm = FALSE`.

I've allready implemented this for functions that explicitly include `na.rm` as an argument, for example `stats::sd()`. Here's what I've done.

```
fun0 <- function(f, env = globalenv()){
  fun0 <- match.fun(f)
  if("na.rm" %in% as.character(formals(f))){
    stop("fun `f` does not have `na.rm as an argument`")
  }
  #get name
  if(is.function(f)) {
    fname <- as.character(substitute(f))
  } else {
    fname <- f
  }
  fname0 <- paste0(fname, "0")

  #assign
  formals(fun0)[["na.rm"]] <- TRUE
  assign(fname0, fun0, envir = env)
}
```

So when I call `fun0(sd)`, it creates a function in the global environment calls `sd0()` and has `na.rm = TRUE` as the default.

However, this runs into big problems with `mean()` as it is a generic function. I wonder if anybody has any ideas how you would go about implenting this idea in that situation. I mean I guess one option would be to make a new mean0 class, then make all new mean0.xxxx methods each which correspondes to thh mean.xxx methods, except  I change to `na.rm = TRUE` to similar how I did it above. That seems like a pretty wild solution though -- any other ideas?

Thanks for your help brains trust.

I haven't actually implemented this idea yet, I'm hoping someone has a better option that what I describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? I'm also not sure if this is best practices, but it is possible:

```r
fun0 <- function(f, env = globalenv()){
  params <- as.list(match.call())
  name <- paste0(params$f, "0")
  f0 <- function(x) f(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  assign(name, f0, envir = env)
}

fun0(mean)

mean0(c(2,3,4,NA,1))
#> [1] 2.5

mean(c(2,3,4,NA,1))
#> [1] NA
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and was the sort of approach I was going to do at the start, but I decided that I actually wanted to literally create a new function that was the same as the original, but with the default na.rm argument changed. I'd be interested to see if there's an approach that literally does that out there too.